# Javascript in general not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a serious issue in getting Javascript to work at all. It is enabled in my browser (Firefox) and I even tried to test the code in other browsers...
My code is as follows below. What is the issue?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DRAW</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="draw" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function draw() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('draw').getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(30,96);
                ctx.lineTo(70,66);
                ctx.lineTo(103,76);
                ctx.lineTo(170,15);
                ctx.stroke();
            };
            img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png';
        }   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Call the function for heaven's sake!

Comment: What are you expecting to happen

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Add this `draw()` just before closing script tag. By adding this you will be executing the function

Comment: Thank you @user2181397, you've been a better help than Alon Eitan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try invoking the function.

You can either call `draw()` after the function definition, or you can wrap the whole thing as an immediately invoked function like `(function...)()`;

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DRAW</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="draw" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function draw() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('draw').getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(30,96);
                ctx.lineTo(70,66);
                ctx.lineTo(103,76);
                ctx.lineTo(170,15);
                ctx.stroke();
            };
            img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png';
        })();   
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much for the help. This worked for me. I've had more experience with HTML and CSS than JavaScript, a little bit of help goes a far way.

Answer (score 1):

Zeph's answer is correct, but just so that it's easier for you to see and follows more standard convention, you can just add `draw()` at the bottom of your code so that it will actually execute the code within the function. You have to do this anytime you want to call a function, and doing it the `draw()` way instead of putting the whole thing in parentheses and adding another set allows you to do it multiple times if that's necessary, and it looks nicer, so I think it's the better route.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DRAW</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="draw" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function draw() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('draw').getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(30,96);
                ctx.lineTo(70,66);
                ctx.lineTo(103,76);
                ctx.lineTo(170,15);
                ctx.stroke();
            };
            img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5395/backdrop.png';
        }
        draw(); //Execute the function
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you Kyle. You've been very helpful as well.